# NoSuchElementException using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to learn python/webscraping and want to scrape my bank statements, but am having trouble logging into my by account through selenium.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

username = 'XXXXXXXX'
password = 'XXXXXXXX'
base_url = 'https://www.onlinebanking.pnc.com/alservlet/PNCOnlineBankingServlet'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(base_url)
uname = driver.find_element_by_name('userId')
uname.send_keys(username)

passw = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
passw.send_keys(password)

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('formButton').click()

driver.quit()
```

I'm getting a `NoSuchElementException` when I call the `find_element_by_name()` method:

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e5d0b6d323ff> in <module>()
     11 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     12 driver.get(base_url)
---> 13 uname = driver.find_element_by_name('userId')
     14 uname.send_keys(user)
     15 

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"userId"}
```

I don't exactly understand why I'm getting this error since the login elements clearly exist when I inspect the webpage. Any help/pointers are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the hierarchy of the website, the login form is inside a `frame`.
So you need to switch to it before you select anything inside it, like this:

```
driver.get(base_url)

driver.switch_to.frame('center')  # 'center' is the name of the frame

uname = driver.find_element_by_name('userId')
```

If you need to switch back, you could do this:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```